# Reg not loading of data from json in AgGrid

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, ag-grid-angular

I'm using Ag-grid in angular, for rowData I'm using data from json which is stored in my `assets` folder, and I'm reading the data using HttpClient. But the data is not loading and I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null

But when I tried to print the json data in console, it's displaying correctly:

[image]

The `.ts` file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-staticdata',
  templateUrl: './staticdata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./staticdata.component.css']
})
export class StaticdataComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("assets/user.json").subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.rowData = data;
  })
}
  columnDefs = [
    {field: 'name',header:"Name"},
    {field: 'value',header:"Value" }
];

rowData:any=[];
}
```

The template file is,

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" 
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData | async" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
<br>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add</button> &nbsp;
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Delete</button> &nbsp;
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button> &nbsp;
```

The json file is,

```
[
    {
        "name":"",
        "value":"Only laptop user"
    },
    {
        "name":"",
        "value":"Only Desktop user"
    },
    {
            "name":"",
            "value":"HVD with desktop"
    },
    {
        "name":"",
        "value":"HVD with laptop"
    },
    {
        "name":"",
        "value":"Dual assets laptop and desktop"
    }
]
```

Yes,I want the name column should be empty by now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: No man,I used the json data from git hub's raw file link

Answer (score 0):

You specifiy rowData as async:

> [rowData]="rowData | async"

and then you try to bind data to rowData

> this.rowData = data;

But data variable isn't from async type. the type should be Observable or Promise

As wrote in angular guide:

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. [explantation here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

You can also read how ag-grid suggest to bind rowData when using async pipe [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/)

Try this convention:

this.rowData = this.http.get("assets/user.json");